# Finding send function for tcp packets in game client

Tags: ollydbg

I am trying to find the function that sends packets to the server in a game client. I have read many tuts about finding the SEND function. But they are not helpful in finding in my case.

So i started as follows:

1. I first attached the game client in ollydbg.Then found all the executable modules.
2. Then opened the `client.exe`. Further i searched for all intermodular calls.
3. Then I searched for the SEND function. I got Five `SendMessage()` functions.

From this step I don't understand what to do further.

Answer (score 9):

While in the CPU/Disassembly window, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (for "Goto"). Type "send" and press the <kbd>OK</kbd> button. This should bring you to the address of the `send()` function in WS2_32.dll and you can set a breakpoint on this address.

Comment: I have found this in ollydbg:
65477994   . FF15 304ADA65                 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&WS2_32.#19>]        ; \send
This is triggered every time when i send a chat packet.What next??

Comment: There is no "what's next' according to your original question. You asked for finding the function that sends packets to the server, this is your answer and it seems to be valid according to your feedback. You'll need to provide more details what you want to achieve. This is also better to do in a new question.

Comment: Basically my primary goal is to get the data from packets that a game sends to its a server.Next i want to decrypt it-my secondary goal.

Comment: @user2692230 that actually is a different question but let me help you out [proxocket](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm#proxocket) is an anwesome base/skeleton to get you started. There is a more verbose description on that project found in [this blog](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-01&post=Proxocket---A-Winsock-Proxy-Sniffer).

Comment: But that prog only captures packets.I want to decrypt the packets.

Comment: @user2692230 that is a skeleton. You can add your decryption into that in no time. Or did you honestly expect a generic "I decrypt anything" tool?

Comment: Sorry to say but i am total noob at using the program.Can you tell me program that will automatically find which function of the game client is sending packets and which one is encrypting them??Shall i tell you the game's name that i am trying to work with??